# Regular expression for GST Identification Number (GSTIN)

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex for the [GST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goods_and_Services_Tax_(India)) number in India?

You can read more about the GST numbers in *[What is GST Number? – Know your 15 Digits GSTIN](https://cleartax.in/s/know-your-gstin)*. On a summary level, the number is represented as

- List item. The first two digits of this number will represent the state code as per [2011 Census of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Census_of_India)
- The next ten digits will be the [PAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_account_number) number of the taxpayer
- The thirteenth digit will be assigned based on the number of registration within a state
- The fourteenth digit will be Z by default
- The last digit will be for a check code

Comment: try this `npm i raysk-vali`

Answer (score 58):

Here is the regex and checksum validation for GSTIN:

```
\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}[Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}
```

[image]

**Format details**

1. The first two digits of the GST Number will represent the State Code as per [the Census (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Census_of_India).
2. The next 10 digits will be same as in the PAN number of the taxpayer.

   - The first five will be alphabets
   - The next four will be numbers
   - The last will be the check code
3. The 13th digit will be the number of registrations you take within a state, i.e., after 9, A to Z are considered as 10 to 35.
4. The 14th digit will be Z by default.
5. The last would be the check code.

---

***Here is the code for verifying/validating the GSTIN number using the checksum in JavaScript***

```js
function checksum(g){
    let regTest = /\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}[Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{1}/.test(g)
     if(regTest){
        let a=65,b=55,c=36;
        return Array['from'](g).reduce((i,j,k,g)=>{ 
           p=(p=(j.charCodeAt(0)<a?parseInt(j):j.charCodeAt(0)-b)*(k%2+1))>c?1+(p-c):p;
           return k<14?i+p:j==((c=(c-(i%c)))<10?c:String.fromCharCode(c+b));
        },0); 
    }
    return regTest
}

console.log(checksum('27AAPFU0939F1ZV'))
console.log(checksum('27AASCS2460H1Z0'))
console.log(checksum('29AAGCB7383J1Z4'))
```

[GST regex and checksum in various programming languages](https://github.com/tk120404/gst)

Comment: it also validates 27AASCS2460H1Z0-xxxxxxx which is not a valid gstin

Comment: @penduDev check the answer now

Comment: @tk120404: The above `checksum` function returns `267` as output for input `iikkk`. What does this mean? 
The function should return `true` OR `false` only. 
Can you please explain this behaviour?

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala the checksum function assumes that the input will be in valid format checked against the above given regex

Comment: @tk120404: Ok thanks. Though a generic method for validating GSTIN number regardless of the input format would have really helped!

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala. Tx for the suggestion. It has been updated now

Comment: @tk120404 - What is 'p' from the line above `p=(p=(j.charCodeAt(0)<a?parseInt(j):j.charCodeAt(0)-b)*(k%2+1))>c?1+(p-c):p;`

Comment: This will fail for *32AADCK5978M1Z0*

Answer (score 20):

Here is the regex that I came up with:

```
/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/
```

According to [H&R Block India GSTIN guide](https://www.hrblock.in/guides/what-is-gst-identification-number.aspx), the 13th 'digit' (entity code) is "an alpha-numeric number (first 1-9 and then A-Z)". That is, zero is not allowed and A-Z represent 10-35. Hence the `[1-9A-Z]` is more accurate than `[0-9]`.

The last digit, "check digit", is indeed alphanumeric: `[0-9A-Z]`. I have independently confirmed by obtaining and testing actual GSTINs.

Answer (score 12):

The correct validation for GSTIN should be

```
^([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-7])([a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[1-9a-zA-Z]{1}[zZ]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1})+$
```

The first 2 digits denote the State Code (01-37) as defined in the Code List for Land Regions.

The next 10 characters pertain to PAN Number in AAAAA9999X format.

13th character indicates the number of registrations an entity has within a state for the same PAN.

14th character is currently defaulted to "Z"

15th character is a checksum digit

This regex pattern accommodates lower and upper case.

Comment: This is the best answer. The regex validates the state code too. The state code range as of now (feb 2018) is 01-37.

Comment: why you are using small letters while only capital letters are there in gst

Answer (score 6):

To add to the previous answers, this answer also provides a code snippet for the **checksum digit**.

```
public static final String GSTINFORMAT_REGEX = "[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[1-9A-Za-z]{1}[Z]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1}";
public static final String GSTN_CODEPOINT_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static String getGSTINWithCheckDigit(String gstinWOCheckDigit) throws Exception {
    int factor = 2;
    int sum = 0;
    int checkCodePoint = 0;
    char[] cpChars;
    char[] inputChars;

    try {
        if (gstinWOCheckDigit == null) {
            throw new Exception("GSTIN supplied for checkdigit calculation is null");
        }
        cpChars = GSTN_CODEPOINT_CHARS.toCharArray();
        inputChars = gstinWOCheckDigit.trim().toUpperCase().toCharArray();

        int mod = cpChars.length;
        for (int i = inputChars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int codePoint = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < cpChars.length; j++) {
                if (cpChars[j] == inputChars[i]) {
                    codePoint = j;
                }
            }
            int digit = factor * codePoint;
            factor = (factor == 2) ? 1 : 2;
            digit = (digit / mod) + (digit % mod);
            sum += digit;
        }
        checkCodePoint = (mod - (sum % mod)) % mod;
        return gstinWOCheckDigit + cpChars[checkCodePoint];
    } finally {
        inputChars = null;
        cpChars = null;
    }
}
```

Sources:

- [GST Google Group Link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gst-suvidha-provider-gsp-discussion-group/lwo9ZUzXonY/pkXhoQpdAwAJ),
- [Code Snippet Link](http://developer.gstsystem.co.in/pages/apiportal/data/gsp/download/GSTIN_Validation_SampleCode.zip)

Comment: While this code snippet could be useful, please include necessary comments to explain it better.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Below is the GSTIN format]

**This is a 100% accurate regex of GSTIN, as it checks everything mentioned in the above image.**

```
[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[ABCFGHLJPTF]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}
```

Comment: perfect, As its validate everything as per GSTIN format

Answer (score 3):

I used this one and checked it against 30+ GSTINs, and it worked flawlessly.

```
/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/
```

The last check digit also seems to be alphanumeric in some of the GSTINs I came across.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

It is working as per GSTIN.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

The correct `regex` for GSTIN is as:

```
^([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-7])([A-Z]{5})([0-9]{4})([A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1})([Z]{1})([0-9A-Z]{1})+$
```

It is correct and have been applied to more than 300 valid taxpayers whom you can validate from [this link](https://services.gst.gov.in/services/searchtp).

Answer (score 2):

Try this one with jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("gst", function(value3, element3) {
    var gst_value = value3.toUpperCase();
    var reg = /^([0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]{1})[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){3}){0,15}$/;
    if (this.optional(element3)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (gst_value.match(reg)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }, "Please specify a valid GSTTIN Number");

  $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
      gst: {
        required: true,
        gst: true
      }

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form submitted');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>GSTTIN #</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="gst" value="" id="input-gst" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

My working regex is

```
/^([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-8])[A-Z]{3}[ABCFGHLJPTF]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}/
```

According to 38 States as of the year 2021.

Comment: This is perfect after checking almost every regex.

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be:

```
/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}Z[0-9]{1}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex could be:

```
/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}Z[0-9]{1}?$/
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct GSTIN validation will be covering 27 states of India,

```
^([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-7])([a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[1-9a-zA-Z]{1}[zZ]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1})+$
```

Comment: Explain your answer, why do you think your answer is better than others?

Comment: Hi @DPVenkatesh,
this regex consider lowercase letters as well in GSTIN, so its better to match a gstin without taking care of lowercase or uppercase of value,

for more details about this regex, pls check this [link](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%5B0%5D%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B1-2%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B3%5D%5B0-7%5D%29%28%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B5%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B1%7D%5B1-9a-zA-Z%5D%7B1%7D%5BzZ%5D%7B1%7D%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%7B1%7D%29%2B)

Answer (score -1):

If you want a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) library, you can use *[GSTIN Validator](https://npmjs.org/gstin-validator)*:

```javascript
var validator = require('gstin-validator');
validator.isValidGSTNumber('12AAACI1681G1Z0'); // Returns a Boolean value.
validator.ValidateGSTIN('47AAACI1681G1Z0'); // Returns a response string with an error message
validator.getGSTINInfo('12AAACI1681G1Z0'); // Returns metadata for GSTIN based on the followed numbering scheme.
```